# What's the simplest way to sort an ArrayList containing only strings?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting

I saw that if I am sorting a custom class, then I must implement the IComparable Interface.
But in this case, I cannot control the "string class".

Thank you.

Comment: String already implements IComparable, which is why the List.Sort mentioned below works. :) The same will work for any class that has it implemented (including your custom classes if you have implemented it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of ArrayList use List to prevent from cating, but in all do `mylist.Sort()` see [Array List Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.sort.aspx) and [List Sort Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

There is an [overload of the `Sort` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e743hdt.aspx) that allows you to specify an `IComparer` to use.

Answer (score 2):

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx

```
// Sorts the values of the ArrayList.
theArrayList.Sort();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `ArrayList` for a reason? It's the pre-generic legacy collection and has been replaced with `List` for all intents and purposes. If you're using list then you can just use the `sort()` method and it'll handle everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd recommend using `List<string>` instead of `ArrayList`. This will provide you with a `.Sort()` method that will "just work".

Otherwise, you can use LINQ to do this from an ArrayList like:

```
 // This makes a new List<T>
 var sorted = arrayList.Cast<string>().OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
```

Using [ArrayList.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k6e334t.aspx) would be more efficient, and it will sort in place instead of copying...

```
 arrayList.Sort();
```

Comment: Array List have sort method like list.

Comment: Why IComparable? there is no need to this in this case.

Comment: String already implements IComparable.  When you call ArrayList.Sort on an ArrayList filled with strings, it is casting each item it contains into IComparable and comparing each item (using an algorythm) to determine how to sort.

Comment: I wanted the simplest. Thanks anyway.